# How would you iterate over a select element's options in Jquery and coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I need to basically turn a select element into a set of hidden fields to communicate with a rails app, so need to iterate over every element, I can only find out how to iterate over arrays, I am probably missing something dumb here I know but can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you know how you'd do it with jQuery and not-CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery

```
$("select option").each(function(i, option){
  # do your stuff
});
```

CoffeeScript

```
for option in $("select option")
  # do your stuff
```

Comment: Thankyou, this was perfect, I KNEW I was missing some obvious answer, but was one of those things.

Comment: Will be accepting answer as soon as the site says the time limit is up

Answer (score 2):

Iterate like this,

With select id

```
$('#selectId option').each(function(){

});
```

With class of select

```
$('.selectclass option').each(function(){

});
```

For all select irrespective of id and class

```
$('select option').each(function(){

});
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, I have no idea why I forgot about the ' option' part of the selector.